# SQL: Islands and Gaps

Tags: sql, vertica, gaps-and-islands

I'll try to explain what I need by the example.

I have some table like this one:

```
ID VALUE FROM_DATE   TO_DATE
1    2   1900-01-01  2011-10-01
1    2   2011-10-02  2012-02-11
1    9   2012-02-12  2014-12-03
4    6   1900-01-01  2010-09-20
4    9   2010-09-21  2011-03-09
4    5   2011-03-13  2013-04-03
```

Look at the first two rows. They could be merge in one:

```
1    2   1900-01-01  2012-02-11
```

And now look at the last two rows. There is no values between 2011-03-10 and 2011-03-12. So, we add another one row:

```
4   null     2010-03-10  2011-03-12
```

As a result:

```
ID VALUE FROM_DATE   TO_DATE
1    2   1900-01-01  2012-02-11
1    9   2012-02-12  2014-12-03
4    6   1900-01-01  2010-09-20
4    9   2010-09-21  2011-03-09
4   null 2010-03-10  2011-03-12
4    5   2011-03-13  2013-04-03
```

How could I do this modification by sql query?
Sorry if my question is incomprehensible

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you just want the SQL to insert the missing row with the NULL value? Or are you wanting some SQL logic to automatically detect where there is a gap in time between FROM_DATE and TO_DATE for an ID and then insert the NULL row and relevant dates?

Comment: I need a common algorithm, so it doesn't matter what DBMS I'm using. Imagine Postgres, if you want to. And yes, I want "some SQL logic to automatically detect where there is a gap in time between FROM_DATE and TO_DATE for an ID and then insert the NULL row and relevant dates" and also  I want to merge some rows like I showed in the example.